# MS Access query code disappears from query object

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

When using MS Access queries, I encounter that the command text of the query object is deleted at random intervals.

A query can run smoothly for weeks or months. Users only access it by means of a simple button with a basic `DoCmd.TransferSreadsheet` functionality.

At random intervals, presumably on opening the database, the command text of some queries resets to the default `SELECT;` that you get when creating a new query.

The common thing in all cases is that

- the sql is are rather long
- the query was written in sql (=not created using the GUI) or was created in the GUI and later changed in the sql

In short

- the queries have valid syntax
- nobody is messing with the queries in the query editor
- this happened in several different databases, so it doesnt seem to be a db-specific problem
- there is no vba-code that meddles with query definitions

Here is an example of a query (created via the UI by my coworkers, probably with small changes to the sql code).

```
SELECT Population.StatusMA, Population.PNr, Population.BKey, Population.Nachname, Population.Vorname, d_Zuordnung.Konzernbereich, d_Zuordnung.Geschaeftsbereich, d_Zuordnung.Bereich, d_Zuordnung.Abteilung, d_Zuordnung.Team, Population.BG, Population.FS, d_Geld.Gehaltsart, d_Geld.Anz_Gehalt, d_Geld.Jahresgehalt, d_Geld.Monatslohn, d_Geld.Stundenlohn, d_Geld.Garantiertes_EK, d_Geld.Vereinbartes_EK, [Jahresgehalt]/[Wert] AS [Compa-Ratio], Population.Geburtsdatum, Population.Alter, Population.Altersklasse, Population.Nation, Population.Spr, Population.Geschlecht, Population.Eintritt, Population.DJ, Population.Austritt, Population.Austrittsgrund, Population.PerGru, Population.Vertragsarttext, Population.Jobtext, t_Position.POS_Langtext, d_Zuordnung.GA, d_Zuordnung.Generalagentur, d_Zuordnung.Haus, d_Zuordnung.Buero, d_Zuordnung.Arbeitsort, d_Zuordnung.VG_PNr, d_Zuordnung.Vorgesetzter, d_Zuordnung.BusinessPartner, Sum(IIf([LoA]="V0B" Or [LoA]="SBK",[TOT])) AS [SP/LE lfdJahr], Sum(IIf([LoA]="SJV",[TOT])) AS [LV lfdJahr], Sum(IIf([LoA]="SJP",[TOT])) AS [PP lfdJahr]
FROM (((((((Population LEFT JOIN d_Zuordnung ON Population.PNr = d_Zuordnung.Z_PNr) LEFT JOIN d_Adresse ON Population.PNr = d_Adresse.A_PNr) LEFT JOIN d_Geld ON Population.PNr = d_Geld.G_PNr) LEFT JOIN d_OrgPosJob ON Population.PNr = d_OrgPosJob.F_PNr) LEFT JOIN t_Position ON d_OrgPosJob.F_POS = t_Position.POS_Nummer) LEFT JOIN 0_bur_infopool ON d_Zuordnung.NL = [0_bur_infopool].BURNR) LEFT JOIN MedianFS ON (Population.SobaCH = MedianFS.SoBaCH) AND (Population.FS = MedianFS.FS)) LEFT JOIN PSIANE2_aktuell ON Population.PNr = PSIANE2_aktuell.Stammnr
WHERE (((IIf([Statusma]="Zukünftig",[z_Vertragsart],[vertragsart])) Like "a*" Or (IIf([Statusma]="Zukünftig",[z_Vertragsart],[vertragsart])) Like "d*" Or (IIf([Statusma]="Zukünftig",[z_Vertragsart],[vertragsart])) Like "m*" Or (IIf([Statusma]="Zukünftig",[z_Vertragsart],[vertragsart])) In ("H1","H2")) AND ((IIf([Z_Status]=2,"Zukünftig",IIf([StatusMA]="Aktiv","Aktiv","Inaktiv"))) Like [StatusMA]) AND ((IIf([A_Status]=2,"Zukünftig",IIf([StatusMA]="Aktiv","Aktiv","Inaktiv"))) Like [StatusMA]) AND ((IIf([F_Status]=2,"Zukünftig",IIf([StatusMA]="Aktiv","Aktiv","Inaktiv"))) Like [StatusMA]) AND ((IIf([G_Status]=2,"Zukünftig",IIf([StatusMA]="Aktiv","Aktiv","Inaktiv"))) Like [StatusMA]))
GROUP BY Population.StatusMA, Population.PNr, Population.BKey, Population.Nachname, Population.Vorname, d_Zuordnung.Konzernbereich, d_Zuordnung.Geschaeftsbereich, d_Zuordnung.Bereich, d_Zuordnung.Abteilung, d_Zuordnung.Team, Population.BG, Population.FS, d_Geld.Gehaltsart, d_Geld.Anz_Gehalt, d_Geld.Jahresgehalt, d_Geld.Monatslohn, d_Geld.Stundenlohn, d_Geld.Garantiertes_EK, d_Geld.Vereinbartes_EK, [Jahresgehalt]/[Wert], Population.Geburtsdatum, Population.Alter, Population.Altersklasse, Population.Nation, Population.Spr, Population.Geschlecht, Population.Eintritt, Population.DJ, Population.Austritt, Population.Austrittsgrund, Population.PerGru, Population.Vertragsarttext, Population.Jobtext, t_Position.POS_Langtext, d_Zuordnung.GA, d_Zuordnung.Generalagentur, d_Zuordnung.Haus, d_Zuordnung.Buero, d_Zuordnung.Arbeitsort, d_Zuordnung.VG_PNr, d_Zuordnung.Vorgesetzter, d_Zuordnung.BusinessPartner
ORDER BY Population.PNr;
```

Comment: This can not happen, so something is hosed. Try a _Compact & Repair_ or create a new database and import all objects from the old.

Comment: Maybe someone/something is saving a blank query object on an existing name?

Comment: I've had similar issues in the past. Sometimes I've coded in VBA the SQL query text, and then call it from `DoCmd.RunSQL MiSQL` where `MiSQL` is just a string variable that contains a SQL sentence. If this sentence was too complex, sometimes it failed. The solution we found was just typing `DoEvents` before and after executing the query with `DoCmd`. That worked for us. I know it's not the same than you, but you could try. [DoEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns this is what i ended up doing in some databases too, or alternatively storing the code externally in .sql files to be retrieved on execution. Since i inherited a large amount of Access Frontends with hundreds of queries, this isn't practical - especially since I am in the process of replacing MS Access

Answer (score 1):

Do you have nulls in your data set?  Nulls can wreak havoc in your work, tasks, job, etc.  Any arithmetic calculation in VBA with a Null value results in a null value. If one of the values is NULL, the result is Null (blank). According to VBA rules for calculating values, the result is null because a null value is an unknown.

Nulls are not the same value as zero (0). However, in many situations that's exactly what we want. We want to treat Nulls as zeros.

Thankfully, Microsoft Access offers a way around this issue in VBA module code or queries. The NullToZero function (NZ) takes a null value and converts it to zero. You should use this function anywhere a value could be null (like a field that is not required).

You need to handle nulls in the following fashion:

Nz ( variant [, valueifnull ] )

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c

If you don't want to write complex SQL to handle the nulls at run-time, you can handle the nulls in your table first, and then try the query you showed in your original post.

```
UPDATE tblSomeTable
SET Field1 = IIf(Field1 Is Null, 0, Field1),    
    Field2 = IIf(Field1 Is Null, 0, Field2),
    Field3 = IIf(Field1 Is Null, 0, Field3),
    Field4 = IIf(Field1 Is Null, 0, Field4),
    Field5 = IIf(Field1 Is Null, 0, Field5),
    Field6 = IIf(Field1 Is Null, 0, Field6),
    Field7 = IIf(Field1 Is Null, 0, Field7),
    Field8 = IIf(Field1 Is Null, 0, Field8),
    Field9 = IIf(Field1 Is Null, 0, Field9),
    Field10 = IIf(Field1 Is Null, 0, Field10)
WHERE (Field1 + Field2 + Field3 + Field4 + Field5 +
        Field6 + Field7 + Field8 + Field9 + Field10) Is Null
```

Comment: I was not aware `NULL` values (that usually dont bother me at all since few if any aggregating functions are used here) are that much of an issue, and could potentially be the reason that query text is deleted from a stored object. Despite that solution not being practical in the current situation (way too many databases and dependencies, including NULL-Filters), it's still an interesting piece of knowledge! thanks.